# Excel Return Date before another date by another column name

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I have two sheets of data with the following.

I want return the date from sheet 2 on sheet 1 with the start date BEFORE the remove date.  For example.  For Customer A, the remove date is 12/29/2016.  I would want to return the date of 12/20/2014 from sheet 2 as it is the next previous date from the remove date of 12/29/2016 from sheet 1 and is removed prior to the third date of 1/20/2017.  Similarly for Customer B, the date returned would be 11/9/2013.

Vlookup will not work as there are more than one unique value for customer and I had no luck with index and match.  Is there any other possible solution?

Here is an edit.  The Sumproduct and aggregate method for the start date works great.  The issue is I need the last date to be the first record after the replacement date.  So in this case, it would be 2/1/16.  Using the Min or Max sumproduct and aggregate method, I get either 0 or the max date of 3/22/17, which is not what I want.

[image]

Answer (score 2):

Since dates are (for all intents and purposes) numbers, this is really nothing more than a pseudo-MAXIFS question. Try,

```
=aggregate(14, 6, (b2:b7)/((a2:a7="A")*(b2:B7<date(2016, 12, 29))), 1)
```

Comment: Re `MAXIFS` - in the latest version of Excel (if you subscribe to Office 365) that function exists, so you can use something like `=MAXIFS(B2:B7,B2:B7,"<"&C1,A2:A7,"A")`

Comment: It's also in hte Excel 2016 tablet version with or without Office 365.

Comment: Ah, I didn't know that - I'm not an Office 365 subscriber but I've used MAXIFS and MINIFS in Office Online, where it's also available

Comment: Can you please see my edit.  I am having issue with the last date.

Comment: Don't change the conditions of the question after answers have been submitted. You should have chosen one response as the answer and upvoted any of the responses you found helpful. If you have re visions that render these answers inappropriate then you should ask a new question.

Comment: @Jeeped well said

Answer (score 1):

[image]

For those that don't have the latest version of excel and can't use maxifs, we can do an array formula: take the max date that is less than the date corresponding to A

```
=SUMPRODUCT(MAX((A9:A14=A3)*(IF((B9:B14)<B3,B9:B14))))
```

*entered as array formulae (<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Enter</kbd>)*

Comment: Thanks, this worked.  What would I need to change if I wanted to pull the next date and not previous date.  So for the first case, it would pull 1/20/17.

Comment: @Nich do the opposite. `=SUMPRODUCT(Min((A9:A14=A3)*(IF((B9:B14)>B3,B9:B14))))`

Comment: Got it, thanks.  I was making the error of not CTRL SHIFT + ENTER and that was my mistake since I wasn't treating it as an array.  Thanks again!

Comment: @nich, np glad to help.

Comment: Hi created an edit above.  The start date method you told me helped, but the last date does not match with the min method.  I need to return the value of 11/10/14 since it falls immediately after the replacement date.

Comment: nich - it worked for me. you should check your formula if it is an array formula and if you typed parentheses around the formula appropriately. you should also select a response as an answer. '=SUMPRODUCT(MIN(IF((lastdate_range)>last_date,lastdate_range))'